# Una relacion de eloquent en laravel me da problemas

Tags: laravel

Tengo un problema. Al hacer una consulta en el controlador tema me recoge la materia del usuario logueado, pero no me saca los temas relacionados con la materia.

Metodo controlador

[image: Este es el controlador]

Controlador materia

[image: El controlador materia]

Controlador del tema

[image: El controlador del tema]

Error que sale

[image: El error que me sale]

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer la sección [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega tus modelos, controladores y migraciones como texto con formato de código para que podamos ver la información de mejor forma

Comment: De acuerdo me pongo a solucionarlo, gracias

Comment: [es.so] te da la facilidad de insertar código en la pregunta, por lo tanto pon los errores y el código _como texto, con formato_. ¡No se puede copiar código de una imagen! Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es hacer una subconsulta al modelo temas

primero te recomiendo que uses eloquent para las consultas

```
$materias = Materias::with('temas')->get();
```

y luego simplemente puedes recorrer los temas de una materia accediendo a la relacion

```
 foreach($materias->temas as $tema ){
    ....
 }
```